# Why does my scrolling div with text extend beyond its container?

Tags: css, html

Why does my scrolling div with text extend beyond its container vertically?

http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/test.html

I'm not sure what code to show here. That is a div (right column--it circles around, that's why it's right, not left) with 100% height inside a container 'columns' div with 100% height, but former is extending beyond the latter.

Thanks.

Comment: can you make a fiddle ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the extended container, use `display: table`. Set a css property `table` to the container and `table-cell` for their children, as follow:

```
#columns {
    display: table
}

#menuBarLine {
    display: table-cell
}

#galleria {
    display: table-cell
}

#right {
    display: table-cell;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

adding this `display` property will fix your problem.

just keep in mind that anytime you have a split column, use `display: table` property as much as possible because `display: table` gives you flexibility in setting up the container width and height. If the container is like "grids", I will encourage to use `display: table`.

`box-sizing: border-box` changes the way `width` and `height` calculate. Now, `width` and `height` will include the `padding` of the container. Therefore, by using `box-sizing: border-box`, you will almost certainly get the value that you want. I think this should be the default value of the css property `width` and `height`. [READ MORE](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: so close! Notice that when you click on the Image Map, I'm back to square one. And I set the image div to table-cell, so I'm not sure what's going on now.

Comment: I've set the image to come up by default, so you can see. For some reason the image throws it off.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: You are giving it 100% height **and** padding.

The first is an issue because there are buttons above it, and therefore it cannot occupy 100% of the height of the window without forcing the window to scroll.

You can fix this by using calc:

```
height: calc(100% - height_of_button_containerpx);
```

**Note**: pay particular attention to the syntax. Note that there is no space inbetween numbers and units, but there **is** a space between each value and the minus sign. **This is important!**

**Note this too**: `calc()` is CSS3 and is [**unsupported in really old browsers.**](http://caniuse.com/calc)

---

The second: padding is applied **in addition to** height. You are telling the div to have Qpx additional space surrounding its 100% height, and so, since the height cannot be greater than 100%, the window must scroll.

This can be fixed quite easily with box-sizing:

```
#myDiv
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I want to be able to say 100% height because when you bring the image map in, the div is shortened. And I have different sized images for different galleries. I just want to be able to extend the text only to the bottom of the page no matter how much stuff is above it.

Comment: How could I programmatically calculate the height of whatever is above the text, menubarline as well as image map?

Comment: I tried this: <script>var height = $("#menuBarLine").height() + $("#staticImage").height();</script>
        <div id="right" class="right column" style="height: calc(100% - heightpx); box-sizing: border-box; display: block"></div>   DIdn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

calculate the height of the div with ID menuBarLine. and then

```
#columns .right {
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 30%;
height: 96%;//(total height of the parent container of #right div -height of the menuBarLine)
overflow-y: auto;
padding: 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment above. The same thing applies.